# Table already has a primary key defined on it. but it doesnot have any key on it

Tags: key

I need to create a backup of a table.

I scripted the existing table (`Table1`). While executing the script with table name as `Table_backup`, I got an error saying that 'table' already has a primary key defined on it. But it does not have any key on it.

After renaming the existing key on `Table1`, I am able to create a key.

Can some one explain? Is there any relation between tables, can't we create a primary key constraints with same on different tables of a database?

Comment: Some important information as the technology, server or client side and others are missing. please add those!

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention which RDBMS you are using, but normally the Primary Key field creation carries out the creation of an underlying index with the same name, which is normally required to be unique across the database.

Comment: Thank you, it is a SQL Server

Comment: Was it the issue? If the answer is correct you can accept it / upvote it.